# Fastest possible UDP listener socket in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, performance, sockets, udp

Hello guys I was wondering what would be the fastest possible reading mechanism for UDP packets.

I was thinking about using socket async recieve, which should be the fastest way to receive data. Then having a processing loop in a different thread.

Is this really the fastest possible way to do it?

```
static Socket udpListener;
static byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
static ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> recievedPackets = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    udpListener = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    udpListener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 50000));

    StartRecievingChain();

    // Processing loop
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (recievedPackets.Count == 0)
                Thread.Sleep(50);

            byte[] packet;

            if (recievedPackets.TryDequeue(out packet))
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved {0} bytes", packet.Length);
            }
        }
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void StartRecievingChain()
{
    SocketAsyncEventArgs recieveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    recieveArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    recieveArgs.Completed += ProcessRecievedPacket;

    if (!udpListener.ReceiveAsync(recieveArgs))
        ProcessRecievedPacket(null, recieveArgs);
}

static void ProcessRecievedPacket(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            StartRecievingChain();

            byte[] data = new byte[e.BytesTransferred];
            Array.Copy(e.Buffer, data, e.BytesTransferred);
            recievedPackets.Enqueue(data);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        e.Completed -= ProcessRecievedPacket;
        e.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything involving `Thread.Sleep` just *can't* be the fastest way ;-)

Comment: I'm not talking about processing packets but recieving them and thread sleep is in processing loop which does not have to do anything with recieving data performance.

Comment: "Receiving data performance" - your code isn't doing the receiving; that happens in the device driver. What actual bottleneck are you concerned with?

Comment: Of course I mean receiving data on application (not system) level and that kind of receiving I'm doing and that kind of receiving I can affect so I don't understand what you are trying to say. Anyway I'm receiving RTP packets from RTSP server. And I want to minimize packet lost, so far I have been able to decrease packet lost from 5 to 1 percentage. And I would like to improve it as much as it could be.